# Not able to replicate form array using searchParams

Tags: javascript, php

I have this input `<select class="form-select" name="filters[]">`, when I submit the form I get in the url this format: `https://example.com/search?filters%5B%5D=post`

where `post` is the value of the option selected. Now I'm building a load more system with AJAX, so I need to replicate the `filter` param, so tried:

```
let url = new URL('<?= base_url('search') ?>');
url.searchParams.append('filters', JSON.stringify(filters));
```

but the url generated by JS is difference:

```
/search?filters%5B%5D <- correct
/search?filters=%5B%22post%22%5D <- incorrect
```

what I did wrong?

Comment: Why do you feel you need to manually build the URL query string? You almost never have to do that. Can you describe what you're trying to do a bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the current output, `filters` is an array containing a single string: `["post"]`

```js
console.log( decodeURIComponent("%5B%22post%22%5D") )
```

To get the desired query string,

- Based on the `name` attribute on the `select`, the key should be `"filters[]"`, not `"filter"`
- The value must be a string like `"post"`. You are passing a JSON string of an array like `'["post"]'`

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams()
params.append("filters[]", 'post')

console.log(
  params.toString()
)
```